# Remove duplicate objects from series in Rebol

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2

In R2 and R3, I can use `unique` to remove duplicate items from a series:

```
>> a: [1 2 2 3]
>> length? a
== 4
>> length? unique a
== 3
```

How can I perform the same operation on a series of objects? e.g.,

```
b: reduce [
    make object! [a: 1] 
    make object! [b: 2] 
    make object! [b: 2] 
    make object! [c: 3]
]
>> length? b
== 4
>> length? unique b
== 4  ; (I'd like it to be 3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of the equality check in UNIQUE and the other set operations appears to be `Cmp_Value`, and the way the comparison is done is to subtract the frame pointers of the objects.  If that subtraction is zero (e.g. these are the SAME? object) then the comparison is considered a match:

[f-series.c Line 283, R3-Alpha open source release](https://github.com/rebol/rebol/blob/25033f897b2bd466068d7663563cd3ff64740b94/src/core/f-series.c#L283)

If you look at the surrounding code you'll see a call to Cmp_Block in that same routine.  In the case of Cmp_Block it does a recursive comparison, and honors the case sensitivity...hence the difference between how blocks and objects act:

[Cmp_Block() in f-series.c](https://github.com/rebol/rebol/blob/25033f897b2bd466068d7663563cd3ff64740b94/src/core/f-series.c#L151)

Given that it is written that way, if you would like a UNIQUE operation to be based on field-by-field comparison of objects vs. their identity, there's no way to do it besides writing your own routine and calling EQUAL?...or modifying the C code.

Here is a short hack not requiring changing the C source, which does a MAP-EACH over the output of UNIQUE.  The body filters out any EQUAL? objects that have already been seen (because when the body of a MAP-EACH returns unset, it adds nothing to the result):

```
my-unique: function [array [block!]] [
    objs: copy []
    map-each item unique array [
        if object? :item [
            foreach obj objs [
                if equal? item obj [unset 'item break]
            ]
            unless unset? :item [append objs item]
        ]
        :item ;-- if unset, map-each adds nothing to result
    ]
]
```

Unfortunately you have to use a BLOCK! and not a MAP! to keep track of the objects as you go, because MAP! does not currently allow objects as keys.  If they had allowed it, they would have probably had the same issue of not hashing field-equal objects the same.

*(Note: Fixing this and other issues are on the radar of the Ren-C branch, which in addition to now being the fastest Rebol interpreter with [fundamental fixes](https://trello.com/c/4Kg3DZ2H), also has a bit of [enhancements to the set operations](https://trello.com/c/KvUZ5zEb).  Discussions in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red))*

Comment: Just wanted to add a note that this is R3-only, but works great there. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

EQUAL? and SAME? returns true for objects only if they are same object references.
I wrote a function to check similarity between objects, it returns true if two objects have same words with same values and same types:

```
similar?: func [
    {Returns true if both object has same words in same types.}
    o [object!] p [object!] /local test
][
    test: [if not equal? type? get in o word type? get in p word [return false]]
    foreach word sort first o test
    foreach word sort first p test
    true
]
```

You can test as follow:

```
>> o: make object! [b: 2]
>> p: make object! [b: 2]
>> equal? o p
== false
>> same? o p
== false
>> similar? o p
== true
```

You may use it in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
unique+: func [array [block!]] [
    objs: copy []
    map-each item unique array [
        if object? :item [
            foreach obj objs [
                if equal-object? :item :obj [unset 'item break]
            ]
            if value? 'item [append objs item]
        ]
        ;-- If unset, map-each adds nothing to result under R3.
        ;   R2 behaves differently. This works for both.
        either value? 'item [:item] [()]
    ]
]

equal-object?: func [
    "Returns true if both objects have same words and values."
    o [object!] p [object!]
][
    if not equal? sort words-of o sort words-of p [return false]
    foreach word words-of o [
        if not equal? o/:word p/:word [return false]
    ]
    true
]
```